# Why does Linq need a setter for a 'read-only' object property?

Tags: linq, readonly, setter, executequery

I'm using a Linq DataContext.ExecuteQuery("some sql statement") to populate a list of objects

```
var incomes = db.ExecuteQuery<IncomeAggregate>(sqlIncomeStatement(TimeUnit));
```

The `IncomeAggregate` is an object I made to hold the result of the records of this query.

One of the properties of this object is YQM:

```
public int Year { get; set; }
public int Quarter { get; set; }
public int Month { get; set; }

public string YQM 
{ 
    get { return string.Format("Y{0}-Q{1}-M{2}", Year, Quarter, Month); } 
}
... more properties
```

Everything compiles OK, but when it executes the Linq I get the following error:

> Cannot assign value to member 'YQM'. It does not define a setter.

But clearly, I don't want to 'set' it. 
Y, Q and M are provided by the query to the database. YQM is NOT provided by the query.
Do I need to change the definition of my object somehow? 
(I've just started using Linq and I'm still getting up to speed, so it could be very simple)

Comment: Another option I tried is to just put in a 'dummy' setter:`private set { ;}`

Comment: @JacksonPope: I was hoping to find a way to let Linq know that is doesn't have to load this value from the database. In the rest of my code I prefer to use YQM as a property.

Comment: I also noticed that when I add a property to a LinqToSql generated class using a partial class that it **IS** possible to have only a getter in that partial class.

Comment: This question looks similar to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707706/ignore-read-only-class-properties-when-using-datacontext-executequeryt).  They came to the same `private set { ;}` solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I finally wound up just making the setter private

```
public string YQM {
    get 
    { 
        return string.Format("Y{0}-Q{1}-M{2}", Year, Quarter, Month); 
    }

    private set { ;} 
}
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Linq is assuming that the *properties* of this object are values to load from the database, and clearly it can't set the `YQM` property because it has no setter. Try making YQM a method instead:

```
public string YQM() 
{ 
    return string.Format("Y{0}-Q{1}-M{2}", Year, Quarter, Month);  
}
```